# Find the maximum value of Q(x,y)

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Find the maximum value of Q(x,y) = $-4x^2 + 4xy - 4y^2$ on the ellipse
$4x^2 + y^2 = 4$.

So I searched how to find the maximum value of a function and I began by solving the ellipse for $y^2 = 4 - 4x^2$. I plugged that into the above function and this is where I get stuck.

To plug it into 4xy, I need to square root the ellipse correct? Wouldn't it make it super messy once I take the derivative of the function and try to solve for x?

Please help, I'd appreciate it greatly!

Comment: Do you know about Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: I am unaware, but I can look at videos/ notes online to find out.

Comment: In what context did this problem come up? It looks typical of a Lagrange multiplier exercise, but it also involves a quadratic form and conic, so it’s not immediately clear what you’re expected to use to solve it.